# Noiseless Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

Why does a **noiseless** GP **interpolate** the data? That is, why is it that the conditional $p(f_*|X_*, X, f)$ has **no uncertainty** on points $X_*=X$ ?

I believe this result should be derived from the expression for the conditional:

[image]

If I understand correctly, one should reach the conclusion that  $\Sigma_*$ above becomes 0 when $X_*= X$. How does that exactly happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K_{**} = K(X_*, X_*)$. Therefore, when $X_* = X$:

$$ \Sigma_* = K(X, X) - K(X, X)^T K(X, X)^{-1} K(X, X)$$
$$ \Sigma_* = K(X, X) - I K(X, X)$$
$$ \Sigma_* = K(X, X) - K(X, X)$$
$$ \Sigma_* = 0$$